# Why does an exe not work after copying it?

Tags: windows-10, copy-paste

I was bored and decided to try this experiment:

**I changed the extension of an exe to txt** and copied the contents. It was all jumbled with random symbols. **I then copied it to another txt file and renamed that txt to an exe**. In running that exe I got:

[image]

**The sizes for both the original exe and the copied exe was the same**. So why does this not work? Is there an explanation for this? And is there a better way (by converting it into text first)?

*Hope it makes sense?*

Comment: It does not.  I am able to copy any executable on my machine.  I just can't open an executable in a text editor, because that doesn't make sense, because your copying every single bit.  They have to be exact copies, by copying the binary data as ASCII characters, your not making an exact copy.

Comment: Just using a binary editor, copy the binary, then it should work.

Comment: Because you are probably using ANSI encoding you are stripping out the top bit of every byte.  Per [What is ANSI format?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/702593/278545) "Use of the top-bit-set characters is not defined in ASCII/ANSI as it is a 7-bit character set."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poking *any* binary data through a random text editor will result in undefined and potentially harmful changes to the file, similar to using the "text" FTP transfer mode to transfer a binary file.

Per [What is ANSI format?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/702593/278545)

> Use of the top-bit-set characters is not defined in ASCII/ANSI as it is a 7-bit character set.

So if you are using an ANSI text editor you will likely be stripping out the top bit of every byte and corrupting the file.  You'll have the same number of bytes, and so the file size will be the same, but you'll be missing 1/8th of the data needed for the executable to work.

Smarter text editors *might* keep all the data so long as you save as something like UTF-8 (without BOM), but I without trying it I would not trust it for binary data.

It's much easier to copy-paste the file in a proper fashion using the copy routine of Explorer (or equivalent thereof) as it will be an *exact* copy rather than assumed to be text by a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that the text editor you used either screwed up the non-printable characters, screwed up the line endings, or both.

**Non-printable characters:** There are many character sets, such as ASCII and Unicode, each supporting one or more encodings. Encodings define mappings from numbers (groupings of binary data) to characters (or "code points" in a character set). Among the many character sets and encodings, the Unicode character set (a superset of ASCII) and the UTF-8 or UTF-16 encodings for it (both of which are based on ASCII, in different ways) are probably the most common. However, not all numbers map to "real" characters. In some encodings, certain binary values are not a valid character. Also, some of these characters are "control" characters intended for use on stuff like really ancient remote teletype machines. Some are weird stuff, like the "bell" character (which makes a beep if you print it to the console). There's also the NULL character (typically encoded as 0, all bits unset) which is used to indicate the end of a string (blob of text) in some common programming languages like C; text editors are likely to not handle these gracefully, but they will appear in an executable file.

Anyhow, a text editor won't know how to represent these. It might just show them as squares or something, but then when you copy it, it might copy the characters as squares, and not as their underlying character codes. Or when you paste it, it might do something similar. Since EXE files are composed of machine code (binary data, which is not intended to be represented as text), it'll contain a bunch of these non-printable characters.

**Line endings:** There are two characters that are (sometimes) used for line endings in most character sets. These are the *carriage return* (in an old teletype, this meant "move the print head back to the left edge") and the *line feed* (advance to the next line down on the page). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). Windows uses both, usually paired; if a line doesn't end in a CRLF, some editors will think the line didn't end at all and just put an invisible character (you'll "trip" over it if you're using the arrow keys to move left/right, your cursor will appear to not move). Other editors will treat CRLF, LF alone, or even CR alone (though nothing since classic MacOS has used that line ending) all as valid line endings.

The problem comes when you copy-paste something with inconsistent line endings. A lot of text editors are "smart" enough to "fix" your line endings. On a Windows system, that probably means converting all solo LF, and probably also solo CR, into CRLF combos. This is adding new data into the EXE, which of course changes what the machine code means.

As @Ramhound's comment says, if you want to copy-paste the contents of an EXE (or any other non-text binary file), you need to use a binary editor (most of these are usually called *hex editors*, because the represent each byte in the file as a hexadecimal value, from 00 to FF, though they will also decode the printable ones into text for you). Binary editors aren't going to miss unprintable characters, or try to "fix" your line endings, or anything else like that.

Comment: "There are actually lots of character sets, but UTF-8 and UTF-16 are probably the most common". UTF8/16 are not character sets, they are encodings.

Comment: Yeah, tweaked the wording a bit. Still kind of awkward but should be better.

Comment: Are you able to help with this? https://superuser.com/questions/1627787/why-does-copying-text-between-notepad-files-create-files-with-different-bytes