# Why does copying text between Notepad++ files create files with different bytes?

Tags: pdf, notepad++, encoding, character-encoding

I've created a simple pdf [`hi.pdf`] with the word `hi` and when I open it in Notepad++, its encoding is ANSI, which I assume is Notepad++'s best guess, with it opening successfully when I *Save as* `hiSaveAs.pdf`.

However, when I copy the contents of `hi.pdf` from Notepad++, pasting into a new file and saving as `hiANSI.pdf` with an encoding of ANSI, the file is corrupted and can't be opened:

```
Error, failed to load pdf document.
```

- When I re-open `hiANSI.pdf` in Notepad++, it has UTF8 listed as the encoding and when I compare it to `hi.pdf`, I notice it has whitespaces where `hi.pdf` has the `NUL` character:

  - **`hi.pdf:`** [image: Screenshot1]
  - **`hiANSI.pdf`:** [image: Screenshot2]
- If I change the encoding of `hiANSI.pdf` to ANSI instead of UTF8, the text differs from `hi.pdf` even more: [image: Screenshot3]

Can someone explain what is happening here?

- Why does *Save as* work, but copying the exact same text into a new Notepad++ file results with a whitespace instead of the `NUL` char?
- Why does Notepad++ think `hiANSI.pdf` is UTF8, but `hi.pdf` ANSI?

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1123301/why-does-an-exe-not-work-after-copying-it) does **not** answer this question.

The MSB is not being stripped. Have a look at the hex comparison:

[image]

For example, why is 0A being added between 0D and 25 (first row, 10th byte)?

**UPDATE:**

I noticed Notepad did much less than Notepad++ in terms of "helping". For example when I saved hi.pdf as hiANSI.pdf using Notepad instead of Notepad++, the only thing Notepad did to help was add `0x0A` (line feed) after `0x0D` (carriage return), and replaced `0x00` (NUL) with `0x20` (space):

[image]

If I saved hi.pdf as hiANSI.bin, it did even less. It just replaced `0x00` with `0x20`:

[image]

In the above two cases, it produced a valid PDF but with "hi" replaced with "IJ":

[image]

**UPDATE**

If I replace the following 0x20 bytes in hiANSI.pdf with 0x00 to match hi.pdf, it displays "hi" instead of "IJ" but with a different font:

[image: Left is hi.pdf, right is hiANSI.pdf]

Here are the two bytes I changed (highlighted in yellow):

[image]

Why does changing these two bytes have this effect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving pdf from Notepad++ creates corrupted file](https://superuser.com/questions/1627583/saving-pdf-from-notepad-creates-corrupted-file)

Comment: @Toto No, I asked that question. It got closed and it said "If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one". So this is me asking a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad++ is a **text**-editor, not a binary editor, so it "corrected" the text
when pasting.

In your example, the `0D` was taken to be carriage-return,
which was taken to be part of the end-of-line character in Windows,
but still missing the `0A` (line-feed).
So Notepad++ has thoughtfully corrected your text.

For more information see Wikipedia:

- [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)
- [Newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

For a freeware hex editor, see for example
[HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/).

Comment: That makes sense. But what about the next byte 25? I can see that's the End Of Medium char, but then why does it add the following 8 bytes, with every other byte being C3? C3 A2 C3 A3 C3 8F C3 93. And on line 15F, why does it add C3 9E after 68? 68 is just the letter "h".

Comment: The `C3` is a very common first byte in Unicode UTF-8 character-encodings. Notepad++ has understood that your file is not simple ASCII text, so decided that it must be in UTF-8 and has therefore translated the non-ASCII characters to UTF-8. Notepad++ is only trying to be helpful.

Comment: You're right. After 68, it has replaced DE with C3 9E, because DE (ANSI) = c3 9e (UTF-8) = LATIN CAPITAL LETTER THORN (Þ). It looks like it has saved the file as UTF-8 even though I selected ANSI in the Encoding dropdown.

Comment: Do you know why it changed "hi" to "IJ"?

Comment: I don't see it in your dumps.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: UTF-8 has multi-byte sequences, so one character may be spread over multiple bytes. Changing one byte may therefore cause changes across more than one character. This might be one explanation, but I have not traced exactly the characters in your dump to verify it.